# How to resolve issue in YouTrack using JS API

Tags: javascript, youtrack, jsapi

I'm trying to resolve issue by action in workflow
But it returns error

```
exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({
  title: "Resolver",
  guard: function(ctx) {
    return ctx.issue.isReported;
  },
  action: function(ctx) {
  workflow.resolve(ctx.issue);
  },
  requirements: {
  }
});
```

Thanks for advice

Comment: what is error message?

Comment: @num8er thanks, I fixed it but still return error;

Comment: just error but I know it calls in this row: `workflow.resolve(ctx.issue);` hot to resolve issue correctly?

Comment: I'm reading manual, there is no `.resolve` method. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/v1-workflow.html#

Comment: @num8er yep. But I guess I can resolve issue in workflow but I don't know how?

Comment: try `action: function(ctx) {ctx.issue.fields.State = 'Resolved';}, requirements: {
    State: {
       name: 'State',
       type: entities.EnumField.fieldType
    }
  }`

Comment: @num8er thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the state of issue.

```
exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({
  title: "Resolver",
  guard: function(ctx) {
    return ctx.issue.isReported && ctx.issue.isReported;
  },
  action: function(ctx) {
    ctx.issue.fields.State = 'Resolved';
  },
  requirements: {
    State: {
       name: 'State',
       type: entities.EnumField.fieldType
    }
  }
});
```